# Problema con Chart.js altura del canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, chart.js

Estoy utilizando chartjs para mostrar unas gráficas y tengo un problema y es que el canvas donde tengo la gráfica se hace demasiado alto.

En el mismo proyecto en desarrollo se ve correctamente, en la réplica del proyecto que tenemos para hacer test se ve bien igualmente pero en producción la gráfica se ve enorme.

Éste es el código de la plantilla:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <h3>{{ almacen }}</h3>
</div>
<canvas id="myChart" class="col-md-8 centrar-div" height="300"></canvas>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive dt-bootstrap" id="tabla_ventas_anuales_almacen" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ "Anyo"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "01"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "02"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "03"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "04"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "05"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "06"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "07"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "08"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "09"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "10"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "11"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "12"|trans }}</th>
        <th>{{ "Total"|trans }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong class="pull-right">{{ anyo }}</strong><br>
                <strong class="pull-right">{{ anyoant }}</strong>
            </td>
            {% for cont in 1..12 %}
                <td>
                    <strong class="pull-right {% if datos[cont] < datosant[cont] %}rojo{% else %}verde{% endif %}">{{ datos[cont]|number_format(2, ',','.') }}</strong><br>
                    <strong class="pull-right ">{{ datosant[cont]|number_format(2, ',','.') }}</strong><br>
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td>
                <strong class="pull-right {% if total < totalant %}rojo{% else %}verde{% endif %}">{{ total|number_format(2, ',','.') }}</strong><br>
                <strong class="pull-right ">{{ totalant|number_format(2, ',','.') }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [
                '{{ "01"|trans }}',
                '{{ "02"|trans }}',
                '{{ "03"|trans }}',
                '{{ "04"|trans }}',
                '{{ "05"|trans }}',
                '{{ "06"|trans }}',
                '{{ "07"|trans }}',
                '{{ "08"|trans }}',
                '{{ "09"|trans }}',
                '{{ "10"|trans }}',
                '{{ "11"|trans }}',
                '{{ "12"|trans }}'
            ],
            datasets: [{
                label: '{{ anyo }}',
                data: [
                    {% for dato in datos %}
                        parseFloat({{ dato }}),
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                borderColor: "rgb(204,127,0)"
            }, {
                label: '{{ anyoant }}',
                data: [
                    {% for dato in datosant %}
                        parseFloat({{ dato }}),
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                borderColor: "rgb(0,202,214)"
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: si cambias el atributo `height="300"` a 150 en `<canvas>` te cambia el alto (?)

Comment: Si lo edito desde el inspector de código sí, pero si lo cambio desde el código antes de cargar la página y al cargar, no cambia nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es muy posible que tengas un problema con los estilos (CSS), porque el tamaño del elemento canvas tiene dos "partes":

- La parte interna es definida por los atributos `height` y `width`. Si un canvas fuese una televisión, podríamos decir que es la cantidad de píxeles de la pantalla y es *parcialmente independiente* del tamaño "físico" del canvas. Es decir, puedes tener dos TVs del mismo tamaño pero uno ser 1080p y otro 4K.
- La parte externa es el el tamaño aparente. Siguiendo con el ejemplo de la televisión, puedes tener una TV 4K de 100cm de ancho o una 4K de 200cm, en ambos casos la resolución es la misma y lo que cambia es el tamaño del pixel. Este valor es por defecto igual al de la parte interna; de esta manera el pixel de dentro es del mismo tamaño que el de fuera. Pero esto deja de ser así tan pronto como uses estilos para modificar su tamaño.

Por tanto, cambiar el tamaño del canvas usando sus atributos puede no servirte de nada, necesitas cambiarlo mediante estilos. En el siguiente ejemplo verás 3 elementos `canvas`, con 3 "resoluciones" distintas pero con el mismo tamaño aparente. Al intentar plasmar 3 veces el mismo dibujo (3 cuadrados), se ven de distinto tamaño.

```js
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');

canvases.forEach(canvas => {
  console.log('Altura:',canvas.height,'px ,anchura',canvas.width);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
  ctx.clearRect(45, 45, 60, 60);
  ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border : 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Ahora hago lo contrario, 3 elementos canvas con mismo tamaño interior pero distinto tamaño exterior:

```js
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');

canvases.forEach(canvas => {
  console.log('Altura:',canvas.height,'px ,anchura',canvas.width);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(2, 2, 16, 16);
  ctx.clearRect(4, 4, 12, 12);
  ctx.strokeRect(6, 6, 8, 8);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border : 1px solid red;
}

canvas+canvas {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  border : 1px solid red;
}

canvas+canvas+canvas {
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  border : 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="50" height="25"></canvas>
<canvas width="50" height="25"></canvas>
<canvas width="50" height="25"></canvas>
```

Como ves, los tres tienen el mismo tamaño interno (el dibujo es igual proporcionalmente), pero aparentemente son distintos. La diferencia entre los pixeles internos puede ser tan grande que el dibujo empieza a verse borroso por el efecto lupa (en el segundo canvas). Si mantenemos la proporción 1:1, es el tercer canvas el que tiene el tamaño "correcto"